# Copying row from scrolled_window to clipboard

Tags: python

I'm trying to copy content of a row being displayed from a treeview, to use in a separate editor program. I found a potential solution using Tkinter and the clipboard_append() function, which seems to work within the original script, but does not modify the system clipboard and thus make the data available to the editor program. Obviously I am missing something and need at least a few hints. Using pyperclip seems like overkill for my needs, which are simply to lookup entries in a membership MySQL database with some 24K rows and copy a single selected row into an editor program.

Comment: Is the treeview being displayed in a Tkinter program? Also which OS is this for?

Comment: No, it's in a scrolled_window that's part of a script which includes Tkinter, but only for the purpose of getting clipboard access. The data entry to initiate the search is a separate toplevel window, and the treeview is in a child scrolled_window. The OS is Linux, specifically xubuntu 16.04.1. I've since discovered that if I call Tk.mainloop() the data is visible to the external editor, but then I'm unable to quit the original script (because, of course, the Tk window's mainloop doesn't provide any control to get back to the non-Tk window). I suspect I'm trying to mix apples and oranges here!

Comment: It's getting a bit clearer, though. Been too many years since my last exposure to event-driven program design!

Comment: You don't _need_ `root.mainloop`. You can use [root.update](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method), or `update_idletasks` to force the GUI to handle events and update itself, and then you won't be stuck in a loop. I don't know if that's enough to solve your problem, and I suspect you're right about the apples & oranges thing. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try those functions and report what happens. Since this is a purely Q&D tool, not intended for public use or even by co-workers, I don't mind a bit of fruit salad if it can be made functional -- and this is the first time I've tried to do anything with Tk; the original script was put together from examples found in a tutorial about working with boxes, that I can no longer identify, and has worked well for several years. Then I decided it would be nice to be able to put the result on the clipboard, rather than doing a screenshot and OCR to put a result into a document being edited.

Comment: Neither update function works, unfortunately. However I can leave the root window visible, use mainloop inside the callback that does the copy actions, then kill the rootwindow via the "X" on its title bar to end the callback, and the data goes to CLIPBOARD for so long as the callback runs. That gives me a time window in which to paste it elsewhere, which is workable though quite ugly. Gotta study more! Thanks again for chiming in!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I found an answer at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pygtk/pygtk_clipboard_class.htm in the example on that page, and it took very little coding and NO added modules in the script! These three lines did the trick when added to my get_selection callback:

```
  self.clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
  self.clipboard.set_text(text)
  self.clipboard.store()
```

Thanks again for all suggestions. This is a great place to exchange ideas.